# Spring Boot @ConfigurationProperties - getting all property keys programmatically?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.3 and the new type-safety properties. Currently I have Spring successfully/automagically mapping several properties such as `my.nested.thing1` to a class like below:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class My {
    Nested nested = new Nested();
    public static class Nested {
        String thing1;
        String thing2;
        //getters and setters....
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I programmatically list all the possible properties in a `@ConfigurationProperties` class? Similar to how Spring lists all the common properties at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html. I'd like to print:

```
my.nested.thing1
my.nested.thing2
```

Right now I'm maintaining a list by hand but this makes it very difficult whenever we change or add properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after digging through Spring Boot source code:

```
@PostConstruct
public void printTheProperties() {
    String prefix = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(My.class, ConfigurationProperties.class).prefix();
    System.out.println(getProperties(My.class, prefix));
}

/**
 * Inspect an object recursively and return the dot separated property paths.
 * Inspired by org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getNames()
 */
private Set<String> getProperties(Class target, String prefix) {
    Set<String> names = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    if (target == null) {
        return names;
    }
    if (prefix == null) {
        prefix = "" ;
    }
    PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(target);
    for (PropertyDescriptor descriptor : descriptors) {
        String name = descriptor.getName();
        if (name.equals("class")) {
            continue;
        }
        if (BeanUtils.isSimpleProperty(descriptor.getPropertyType())) {
            names.add(prefix + "." + name);
        } else {
            //recurse my pretty, RECURSE!
            Set<String> recursiveNames = getProperties(descriptor.getPropertyType(), prefix + "." + name);
            names.addAll(recursiveNames);
        }

    }
    return names;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To address your issue of listing all possible options, I'm utilizing key-value properties. It's worth noting that I'm using Spring Boot version 3.0.5 and Lombok in conjunction with Java 17, which is different from your original question.

**My propertie class**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class My {
     private  Map<String, Nested> nested;

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    @Builder
    public static class Nested {
        String field1;
        String field2;
        //getters and setters....
    }
}
```

My application.yaml, but,  you can use the application.properties

```
my:
 nested:
  thing1:
    field1: "field1"
    field2: "field2"
  thing2:
   field1: "field1"
   field2: "field2"
```

In this way, you can inject properties into the service

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class My Service {
     private final My my;

  public void method(String thing){
   final var my.getNested().get(thing)
 
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).